# Azure DevOps How to add test existing test cases by test suite id

Tags: azure-devops, devops

Does anyone, in the DevOps Test Plan UI, if there's a way to add existing test cases to a test suite by test suite id? I can't seem to find a query that will do this. For instance if i have a regression test suite with id 12345 and then later I create a new test suite for a specific release and i want to add the tests cases in suite 12345 by test suite id, is there a way to do that?

[image]

So this will bring up a new window to build a query but in order for me to add the test cases I have to specify each individual id or use tags which can be annoying. I'd like to just reference my regression suite (12345) but can't seem to find a way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to import the test suit with its id and you have to use its name.

Try to right-click on the first Test Suite--> Import test suits

[image]

And then you can type your test suite to import that.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me :/ In the `Select a test plan` dropdown it's just an infinite loading and nothing ever comes up. But what does this option do? Does it make a copy of the tests and test suite?

Comment: In import test suites, as soon as i select the "Select a test plan" dropdown i get an error `The test suite with id xxxxx does not exist` then i just get a loading icon and nothing loads. Any idea what that's about?

Comment: Did you check wheether your user permission has the right of test plan? Under Project Settings-->Permission-->your user account.